# add element into one of two forms by appendTo

Tags: jquery

i have 2 forms in one page.

When i add element (text field) with appendTo , this element is inserted in both forms

How can i fix it?

My current code:

```
<h4>Example</h4>
<form id="aaa">
   <input  name="test1" value="1">
   <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
<form id="bbb">
   <input name="test2" value="2">
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

And javascript:

`$('<input>').attr({ id: 'test-value', name: 'test-value' }).appendTo('form'); $('#test-value').val('demo demo text')`

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XMwx.png)

Link : http://jsfiddle.net/bvotcode/zq5rs0tp/20/

Please help

I only want to add element to form with id ="aaa".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('<input>').attr({ id: 'test-value', name: 'test-value' }).appendTo('form#aaa')
```

Try this